# how to change a theme slug

Tags: theme-development, themes, slug

I've opted to use the Understrap theme as a base theme for development.

How do I safely change the theme slug throughout the theme files, i.e. everywhere `understrap` appears?

Is it simply a case of performing a search and replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a theme name `Hello World` a search and replace should be done in phases.

1. Make sure you do a case sensitive search and replace.
2. Replace `Hello World` with `Example Name`
3. Replace `hello-world` with `example-name`
4. Replace `hello_world` with `example_name`
5. Modify theme folder name
6. Look for any other namespaces that the theme uses and replace accordingly.

These steps will ensure that there is no unintended replacement which may break the theme.

Comment: FTR, the main areas the slug needed to be changed were `<?php
/** * @package understrap`, `<?php _e('message', 'understrap') ?>`, & `get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a search and replace could work. Make a backup, do it and see what happens.

Depending on the theme and your adaptations, there may be some snags, however. For instance, the theme may sometimes derive the slug from the Name in `style.css`. If you change it in one place, but in another it uses the Name and there is a difference, things may not work. There may be a relation with the text domain or with actual file names which do not change with a search and replace.

So, once again, yes, search and replace could work. But there are all kinds of exceptions thinkable, which would lead to errors.